# Salvar grupo de dados no método Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, collection

Estou utilizando o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) para salvar uma lista de dados em meu método adicionar.

Para isso, eu criei uma `ViewModel` com os dados principais a a lista que quero salvar, no método **POST.**

Possuo a `ViewModel` **TipoPrestacaoVencimentoViewModel** que possui os seguintes atributos:

```
public class TipoPrestacaoVencimentoViewModel
{
[Key]
public int TipoPrestacaoId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o nome da Prestação.")]
public string Descricao { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Tipo de vencimento")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha o tipo de Prestação.")]
public string TipoVencimento { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Responsável TCE")]
public string Responsave { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Quantidade de Arquivos")]
public int? QuantidadeArquivos { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o ano da prestação!")]
[Display(Name = "Ano Vigência")]
public string AnoVigencia { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<AnexoPrestacaoViewModel> Anexos { get; set; }
}
```

E passo com ela, uma coleção de **Anexos**:

```
 public class AnexoPrestacaoViewModel
    {
        public int AnexoPrestacaoId { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public string Sequencia { get; set; }
        public byte[] Arquivo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataArquivo { get; set; }
    }
```

Em meu método Adicionar, envio um novo produto à `View`, dessa forma:

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
{
    var recipePrestacao = new TipoPrestacaoVencimentoViewModel();

    return View(recipePrestacao);
}
```

E salvo com o **POST** assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Adicionar(TipoPrestacaoVencimentoViewModel tipoPrestacao)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _prestacaoDB.Adicionar(tipoPrestacao);
        TempData["MensagemSuccess"] = "Prestação adicionada com sucesso!";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(tipoPrestacao);
}
```

E possuo um método para adicionar novo item na `View`:

```
public ActionResult GetNewPrestacao()
{
    return PartialView("_Anexo", new AnexoPrestacaoViewModel());
}
```

Minha `View` está da seguinte forma:

```
@model PrestacaoWeb.Application.ViewModels.TipoPrestacaoVencimentoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar Tipos de Prestações de Conta";
}

<style>
    body .modal-admin {
        width: 900px;
        margin-left: 120px;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Prestacao", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-admin">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@ViewBag.Title</h4>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="bs-example">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dadosPrestacao">Prestação</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Anexo">Anexos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="dadosPrestacao" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                @Html.Partial("_DadosPrestacao")
                            </div>
                            <div id="Anexo" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Anexos</legend>
                                    <div class="new-anexo">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anexos)
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px">
                                        <a id="add-anexo" href="javascript:void(0);">Add Anexo</a>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbtn" />
                            </div>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index", "Prestacao", null, new
                                {
                                    @id = "btnAddPrestacao",
                                    @class = "btn btn-danger"
                                })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#add-anexo').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetNewPrestacao")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.new-anexo').append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

E a `PartialView` que utiliza o **BeginCollectionItem** assim:

```
@model PrestacaoWeb.Application.ViewModels.AnexoPrestacaoViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Anexos"))
{
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sequencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sequencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sequencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataArquivo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataArquivo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataArquivo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Arquivo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label", @align = "right" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Arquivo, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Arquivo, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

O problema é que ao rodar a minha aplicação, eu recebo um  `System.NullReferenceException` vindo do `Collection.cshtml`. Segue o erro completo:

```
Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 
Detalhes da Exceção: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
Erro de Origem: 
Linha 2:  
Linha 3:  <ul>                                 
Linha 4:      @foreach (object item in Model)
Linha 5:      {
Linha 6:          <li>
Arquivo de Origem: c:\Users\renilson.meneguci\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UEM_ES\Fontes\PrestacaoWeb\src\PrestacaoWeb.UI\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Collection.cshtml    Linha: 4 
Rastreamento de Pilha:[NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_Collection_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\ti\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UEM_ES\Fontes\PrestacaoWeb\src\PrestacaoWeb.UI\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Collection.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +727
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1332
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper1 html, Expression1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(HtmlHelper1 html, Expression1 expression) +94
   ASP._Page_Views_Prestacao_Adicionar_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\ti\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UEM_ES\Fontes\PrestacaoWeb\src\PrestacaoWeb.UI\Views\Prestacao\Adicionar.cshtml:67
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +142
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +379
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +108
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

**Nota:** Estou seguindo o modelo [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315184/4843158)

Comment: Qual desses fontes é o `Collection.cshtml`?

Comment: Desculpa a demora @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Eu estava com problemas com minha internet. 
Na verdade, eu não modifiquei o `Collection.cshtml`, ele está igual quando foi instalado pelo Nuget. Eu criei uma `partialView` estou chamando ela no método.

Comment: `EditorTemplates` não é padrão do projeto. Qual pacote NuGet você usou para obtê-lo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez utilizei o `Install-Package BeginCollectionItem`.
Com isso ele já criou essa `View` automaticamente.

Answer (score 2):

O erro começa aqui:

```
<div class="new-anexo">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anexos)
</div>
```

Pelo que diz a mensagem, `Anexos` está nulo. Por isso o erro.

Troque:

```
<div id="Anexo" class="tab-pane fade">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Anexos</legend>
        <div class="new-anexo">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anexos)
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px">
            <a id="add-anexo" href="javascript:void(0);">Add Anexo</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Por:

```
<div id="Anexo" class="tab-pane fade">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Anexos</legend>
        <div class="new-anexo">
            @foreach (var anexo in Model.Anexos) {                    
                Html.RenderPartial("_Anexo", anexo); 
            }
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px">
            <a id="add-anexo" href="javascript:void(0);">Adicionar Anexo</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não analisei muito o seu código, não entendi direito o que seria esse objeto "Model" utilizado no foreach. Não seria:

```
Model.Anexos
```

Mas de qualquer maneira, tem certeza que o objeto Model utilizado no comando abaixo não é NULL?

```
@foreach (object item in Model)
```

Você não pode iterar como foreach sobre um elemento NULL.

Comment: Eu estou seguindo o modelo que postei no final da pergunta, e lá está dessa forma.
Realmente, ele está `null` na inicialização da `View`. Se eu excluir o `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anexos)`, porém gostaria que apresentasse uma opção logo após iniciar a `View`

Comment: @Wise se ele está `null` você não pode iterar sobre ele. Ou define um valor padrão para ele (uma lista vazia) ou adicione um `if` antes de executar este `foreach`

Comment: Vou verificar o agora.